# Pagecontrol and UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, pagecontrol

I'm trying to build an app that uses page control as a main navigation. Here's how it goes i want to have full screen buttons that can be be swiped and when you click on them it takes you to the corresponding view. I know how to implement pagecontrol for images bu not for buttons any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a terrible design, but assuming you have some great reason that I'm just not creative enough to imagine, you don't need to use buttons, you can use images and just add a UITapGestureRecognizer to them and trigger on that event.  In effect, the entire view (image) will be a button.

Comment: I totally agree just a crazy idea a design had and don't have much saying to that jut have to make it work. Hw do i go about implementing the Gresturerecognizer?